# How to get the Id of parent record from child query

Tags: apex, soql

I have requirement to find out the Parent Id from the List and store in a string variable:

```
 List<Case_Associated_Document__c> caseAssoDoc = [Select id,Service_Request__r.id From Case_Associated_Document__c Limit 1];
 System.debug('caseAssoDoc ----'+caseAssoDoc);
```

How can I get the Service_Request__r.id and store it in the separate variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact is a child object and Account is the parent object 
accountID is field API name in contact object referencing relationship to the account object

List contactList = [SELECT AccountID FROM Contact ];

```
set<ID> IDSet = new set<Id>();
for(Contact cot: contactList ) {
  IDSet.add(cot.AccountID );
}

**or**

set<ID> IDSet = new set<Id>();
for(Contact cot: [SELECT AccountID FROM Contact]) {
  IDSet.add(cot.AccountID );
}
```

Comment: let me know if this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can access any field value using **dot notation** **.** If you need to have only the `Id` field from parent object record, you don't have to query the related record but only the `lookup` field of its child. Then simply create a new set of ids and fill this set iterating the returned records.

```
/* Bulkified style */
Set<Id> serviceRequestIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Case_Associated_Document__c> caseAssoDocs = [SELECT Id, Service_Request__c FROM Case_Associated_Document__c];
if (!caseAssoDocs.isEmpty()) {
    for (Case_Associated_Document__c doc : caseAssoDocs) {
        /* serviceRequestIds.add(caseAssoDoc.Service_Request__r.Id); */
        serviceRequestIds.add(caseAssoDoc.Service_Request__c);
    }
}
```

Or just simply declare a new variable and assign it:

```
/* Non-bulkified style */
Id serviceRequestId;
List<Case_Associated_Document__c> caseAssoDocs = [SELECT Id, Service_Request__c FROM Case_Associated_Document__c];
if (!caseAssoDocs.isEmpty()) {
    /* serviceRequestId = caseAssoDocs[0].Service_Request__r.Id; */
    serviceRequestId = caseAssoDocs[0].Service_Request__c;
}
```